# How can I make my Google Places API textsearch query return only a specific zipcode?

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-places-api

I am trying to perform a textsearch using Google's Places API, and I need the query to only return results that are from a specific zipcode.

My current `endpoint_URL` is as follows:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=grocery+store+in+37216&location=37216&region=us&type=grocery_or_supermarket,supermarket,bakery,food&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

I have tried different variations of the query, including putting the zipcode only in the text query, only specifying the zipcode in the location parameter, and specifying both at the same time.

Right now it seems that specifying the zipcode in `query=grocery+store+in+37216` yields the best results, but some of the hits still include incorrect zipcodes.

Does anyone have any suggestions or solutions on how to narrow my results down to only one specific zipcode?

Thanks!

Comment: To further check, what are your expected addresses or the scope locations of the Places Text Search API you want to see? This is because the postal code `37216` corresponds to many addresses.

Comment: Also, correcting the parameters for [Places Text Search API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-text#required-parameters) in your given web request is:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=grocery+store+in+37216&location=(latitude,longitude)&region=us&type=supermarket|bakery|food&key=YOUR_API_KEY